# outlook oauth 2.0 and IMAP

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, office365, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to achieve the authentication for office 365 accounts by using oauth 2.0 ,
i'm using PublicClientApplication and InteractiveRequestParameters method for acquiring access token and in result successfully received access token ,refresh token and id token but when i am using access_token to connect to imap, i am getting error as authentication failure, can anyone please help me out what am i missing here.

have given all the required permissions from azure portal.
here is my code through which i am trying to connect to server

store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "my_email_id, access_token); //here store is imap

properties i have set are:
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");
properties.put("incomingHost", "outlook.office365.com");
properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("outgoingHost", "smtp.office365.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");

Note: when i am providing password instead of access_token , i am successfully able to login but failure while using access_token.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your access token in place of a password. IMAP requires that your client use SASL XOAUTH2 to authenticate. Details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth).

> For example, the SASL XOAUTH2 format to access `test@contoso.onmicrosoft.com` with access token `EwBAAl3BAAUFFpUAo7J3Ve0bjLBWZWCclRC3EoAA` is:
>
> ```
> base64("user=test@contoso.onmicrosoft.com^Aauth=Bearer EwBAAl3BAAUFFpUAo7J3Ve0bjLBWZWCclRC3EoAA^A^A")
> ```
>
> After base64 encoding, this translates to the following string. Note that line breaks are inserted for readability.
>
> ```
> dXNlcj10ZXN0QGNvbnRvc28ub25taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tAWF1dGg9QmVhcmVy
> IEV3QkFBbDNCQUFVRkZwVUFvN0ozVmUwYmpMQldaV0NjbFJDM0VvQUEBAQ==
> ```

Comment: Thank you , will try this once and update you

Comment: hi, can please suggest any way to login to office365 by using access_token, i am a beginner and dont have much idea ,please help me out.